# You should run away. (Who am I)

Tags: riddle

In many people, I am not the first thing you want to have.
Never would you want to give me to your family or friends.
Sadly, I am often inevitable.
Although, some purport to have a cure for me, but mostly they're wrong or lying.
Next generation medical science might help cure me with DNA technology.
I am easy to find, if you know where to look.
Trust me.  I am not what you want.
You should run.

hint

> No hints on this because the solution is staring you in the face.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answer:

> It's an acrostic riddle: INSANITY.

Answer (score 9):

In many people, I am not the first thing you want to have.

> Many people we come across are bald.

Never would you want to give me to your family or friends.

> we don't want our family members of friends to be bald

Sadly, I am often inevitable.

> aging often brings baldness

Although, some purport to have a cure for me, but mostly they're wrong or lying.

> there is no cure for baldness

Next generation medical science might help cure me with DNA technology.

> may be tweaking DNA will help grow hair

I am easy to find, if you know where to look.

> we look at head for baldness

Trust me.  I am not what you want.
You should run.

> No one wants a bald head

Comment: Very clever, and it satisfies most of the requirements, but no.

Comment: Also, there are cultures and subcultures where ROT13(onyq) is good

Answer (score 5):

> Cancer.

In many people, I am not the first thing you want to have.

> Nobody wants to have cancer.

Never would you want to give me to your family or friends.

> Same as before, you do not wish this upon anybody, let alone your family or friends.

Sadly, I am often inevitable.

> Indeed.

Although, some purport to have a cure for me, but mostly they're wrong or lying.

> We do not have a definite cure, yet...

Next generation medical science might help cure me with DNA technology.

> ... we might have it soon. Gene analysis is the tool we have to curing cancer.

I am easy to find, if you know where to look.

> He probably hides under a rock at some beach.

Trust me. I am not what you want.

> You repeat yourself.

You should run.

> I have mighty claws.

Comment: +1 *indeed*, it is one of the conundrums of immortality.

Answer (score 2):

It is best to wait to get old to get wrinkles/
Nobody wants their friends to wrinkle too soon/
We all grow old and get wrinkles/
Many people claim to have youth elixirs to prevent wrinkles but nobody does/
Maybe in the future we can manipulate DNA to stop the aging process/
wrinkles are obvious. Look at  the face.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but no.

Answer (score 0):

> I am easy to find, if you know where to look. Trust me. I am not what
>   you want.

Well, this seems like it would fit very well, iykwim.

> STDs

Answer (score -1):

> Sadness

In many people, I am not the first thing you want to have.

> You don't want your family or friends to be sad.

Never would you want to give me to your family or friends.

> Sadness is inevitable many times.

Sadly, I am often inevitable.

> Antidepressants, many other medicines. Sadly not completely curable.

Although, some purport to have a cure for me, but mostly they're wrong or lying.

> Next generation medical science may change how we feel or remove the ability to feel emotions.

Next generation medical science might help cure me with DNA technology.

> Almost everyone is sad.

I am easy to find, if you know where to look.

> Nobody wants to be sad.

Trust me. I am not what you want.

Yeah we should run.

Answer (score -2):

> Diabetes:

Definitely not the first or even close to the first thing you would want to have

And:

> Wouldn't wish this disease on any loved ones

Inevitable because of:

> genetics and/or one's lifestyle choices

Plus:

> No cure has been proven or even on the table as far as I know?

Easy to find:

> by taking blood sugar/doing CBC/

Finally:

> No one wants diabetes and run while you can since many lose limbs due to this disease